# Centos7 Apache with passenger enabled - vhosting not working for all configs

Tags: apache, passenger, virtualhost, redmine, centos7

Maybe an old topic, but i'm kinda stuck with an actual simple vhost configuration. Maybe I'm just missing something...

I would like to confige a virtual machine with some software products. 
What I already did:
- Jenkins bitnami stack: works fine on dev.company.com:8080/jenkins

Installation of httpd via yum
- Set up my SVN Repository via WebDAV: Works fine as well on port 80 at dev.company.com/repo

Configfile at /etc/httpd/conf.d

```
<Location /repo>
        DAV svn
        SVNParentPath /srv/svn/repositories/
        SVNListParentPath on
        #<LimitExcept>
        # GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "SVN Authorization Realm"
                AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-conf
                Require valid-user
        #</LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

- Installation and Configuration of Redmine with WebRicks. Tested on localhost:3000: works fine
- Running Redmine with Phusion Passenger via HTTPD: works fine on dev.company.com as document Root

Configfile at /etc/httpd/conf.d

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /home/redmine/redmine/public
  ServerName dev.company.com
  ServerAlias www.dev.company.com
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  Alias /redmine /home/redmine/redmine/public
  PassengerLogLevel 3
  RailsEnv production
  PassengerDefaultUser apache
  <Location /redmine>
    PassengerBaseURI /redmine
    PassengerAppRoot /home/redmine/redmine/public
  </Location>

  <Directory /home/redmine/redmine/public>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Options -MultiViews
    RailsBaseURI /redmine
    PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
  </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>

 PassengerPreStart http://dev.company.com
```

now i would like to set up another vhost config file to /opt/project and /var/www/project

My Vhost config Files look like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName dev.company.com/test
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
Alias /test /var/www/html
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    PassengerEnabled off
</Directory>
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /opt/test
ServerName dev.company.com/test2
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
Alias /test /opt/test
<Directory /opt/test>
    Options all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    PassengerEnabled off
</Directory>
```

Always the first config file is read and working on dev.company.com:80.
All following vhost config files are being ignored.

Default httpd.conf file with default Directory setting and just added NameVirtualHost *:80 (default Listen 80). I also included 127.0.0.1 dev.company.com/test... to /etc/hosts file and restarted the httpd service serveral times (and the complete virtual machine as well).

Maybe it's just a simple thing - but i don't have any clue. Does someone has any Idea? I'd really appreciate that!

Comment: Ah I forgot - it's also not possible to setup http://redmine.company.com via vhost and /etc/hosts file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware you can't specific two different DocRoots for the same VH. You'll probably need to use Alias as below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /home/redmine/redmine/public
  ServerName dev.company.com
  ServerAlias www.dev.company.com
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  Alias /redmine /home/redmine/redmine/public

  Alias /test /var/www/html

  Alias /test2 /opt/test

  PassengerLogLevel 3
  RailsEnv production
  PassengerDefaultUser apache
  <Location /redmine>
    PassengerBaseURI /redmine
    PassengerAppRoot /home/redmine/redmine/public
  </Location>

  <Directory /home/redmine/redmine/public>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Options -MultiViews
    RailsBaseURI /redmine
    PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
  </Directory>

  <Directory /var/www/html>
    Options all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    PassengerEnabled off
  </Directory>

  <Directory /opt/test>
    Options all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    PassengerEnabled off
   </Directory>


 </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: oh dear... i just love you :D  Didn't think it's THAT simple that i missed. Thankx a lot! Just didn't get redmine to work as company.com/redmine due to no matching DirectoryIndex.. but i think that cannot be that difficult ;)